# Inverting a digital filter

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, z-transform

I want to understand a technique for calculating the inverse of a digital filter.

Let A be a function from $R$ to $R$ such that
$$
A(0) = 1;\quad A(1) = a_1;\quad A(2) = a_2; \quad\text{, otherwise } A(t) = 0.
$$
The $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of $A$ is
$$
\mathcal{Z}(A)(z) = 1 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}.
$$
The function $A$ defines a digital filter.

The inverse digital filter is a function B from $R$ to $R$ such that $A*B=\delta$, where "$*$" denotes convolution and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function.

I know that I can find $B$ by using partial fraction expansion on 
$$
\mathcal{Z}(B)(z)= \frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}(A)(z)} = \frac{1}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}}
$$ 
to express it in terms that have a inverse $\mathcal{Z}$ transform available in a table of well-known $\mathcal{Z}$ transformations.

The technique I am interested in knowing more about works as follows.

If $r$ is complex number such that $|r|<1$, then the geometric sum is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}.
$$
Let us find $B(1)$. Using the geometric sum we have that 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}(A)(z)} &= \frac{1}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-a_1z^{-1} - a_2z^{-2})^k \\
&= 1  -a_1z^{-1} - a_2z^{-2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-a_1z^{-1} - a_2z^{-2})^k. \\
\end{align}
By inspection we find that the coefficient of the term $z^{-1}$ is $\;-a_1$. Hence, $B(1) = -a_1$.

To find $B(n)$ we continue to evaluate the sum and identify terms.

My questions: Does this work for any function $A$? Does the condition $|r|<1$ matter for this technique to work?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766488/invertibility-of-ma2-process

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works for any $A$ in the form
$$
A(0) = 1;\quad A(1) = a_1;\quad A(2) = a_2; \quad\text{, otherwise } A(t) = 0.
$$
where $a_1 , a_2\in R$, provided that $|r|<1$.

$|r|<1$ is necessary for convergence.